# Export sharepoint online site usage report

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to export sharepoint site usage report for last 30 days  or based on date range.

Do we have api ?

OOB i can only get last 7 days. layouts/15/siteanalytics.aspx?view=19
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Site usage** feature to view usage data for your site **the last 7 days, last 30 days, and last 90 days**.

[image]

[image]

`Note:`

- Site admins, owners, members, and visitors can view site usage data
- Site visitors cannot run external user reports or download the 90-day
  usage report
- Guest users with Site Owner permissions will not have access to site
  analytics or site usage data.

More information, please refer to **[this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-usage-data-for-your-sharepoint-site-2fa8ddc2-c4b3-4268-8d26-a772dc55779e)**.